# RemoteApp session timing out

Tags: remoteapp

I am setting up a Windows 2012 with RemoteApp.

When I run RDP client with RemoteApp activated (just running the app that I want), the session is lost within a couple of minutes and the RDP client disconnects.

When I run RDP client with the same conditions but without RemoteApp (displaying the whole desktop) the session does not timeout, is not lost, and all works as expected.

I have looked at the common options for TimeOut and RDP, but so far I have not found the reason of why RemoteApp is timing out.

Local Group Policy Editor > Local Computer Policy > Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Remove Desktop Services > Remote Desktop Session Host> Session Time Limits

[image]

Local Group Policy Editor > Local Computer Policy > User Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Remove Desktop Services > Remote Desktop Session Host> Session Time Limits

[image]

Server Management > Remote Desktop Services > Collections > My Collection > My Collection Properties > Session

[image]
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you provide a list of the "common options for timeout" you checked, and their current value ?

Comment: @Swisstone added the "common places for rdp session timeout"